# Impossible to update Spyder 4.0.0 using miniconda

Tags: spyder, miniconda, kite

I tried to update my Spyder Application from 3.7 to 4.0.0 but I get the following pop up:

> Spyder crashed during last session.

> If Spyder does not start at all and before submitting a bug report, please try to reset settings to defaults by running Spyder with the command line option '--reset':

> **spyder --reset**

> Warning: this command will remove all your Spyder configuration files located in 'C:\User\......\.spyder-py3).'

> If Spyder still fails to launch, you should consult our comprehensive Troubleshooting Guide, which when followed carefully solves the vast majority of crashes; also, take the time to search for known bugs or discussions matching your situation before submitting a report to our issue tracker. Your feedback will always be greatly appreciated.

And after closing this pop up, I get this error message in the Anaconda Prompt console:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\212676094\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3711, in main
> mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
> File "C:\Users\212676094\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3552, in run_spyder
> main.setup()
> File "C:\Users\212676094\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 960, in setup
> self.completions.start()
> File "C:\Users\212676094\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\completion\plugin.py", line 292, in start
> client_info['plugin'].start()
> File "C:\Users\212676094\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\completion\kite\plugin.py", line 144, in start
> self.client.start()
> File "C:\Users\212676094\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\completion\kite\client.py", line 62, in start
> self.sig_client_started.emit(self.languages)
> TypeError: KiteClient.sig_client_started[list].emit(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'

I tried to uninstall and reinstall miniconda and all dependencies, spyder and all libraries but nothing helped.

I think it's an issue with the KiteClient module as said before. I tried to install Kite but it didn't change anything.

How could I solve it?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Did you open the same question before here in StackOverflow?

Comment: Hello Carlos, no, it wasn't me. Actually, I've already seen a similar topic (not exactly the same) on StackOverflow and no answer was available.

Comment: Ok, I'm in contact with Kite's people right now and we'll try to fix this problem as soon as we can. Until we do, please uninstall Kite to avoid this error. Spyder should start without issues afterwards.

Comment: Do you mean running Spyder in version 4.0.0 without Kite ? Or a downgrade version ?

Comment: Running Spyder 4 without Kite. That should work just fine because the error you reported above is caused by Kite itself.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Do you know a command line to try this ? 
Because Spyder 4 is not launched at all, so i can't access to the parameters directly in the app to disable Kite manually.

Comment: You need to uninstall Kite for now, there's no other way, sorry.